# How to join filling rows with null values in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres i have a table like this

```
id  key value
1   first   x
1   second  y
1   third   z
1   fourth  k
2   first   o
2   second  p
2   third   q
```

The only possible values of column key are

```
key
first
second
third
fourth
```

So this is my second table of interest.

I want to join this two tables adding a row with the same id and key but with null value when the starting table don't have all rows for the keys.

In fact the table that i want to get is this one

```
id  key value
1   first   x
1   second  y
1   third   z
1   fourth  k
2   first   o
2   second  p
2   third   q
2   fourth  [null]
```

How can i do that in simple query? A simple right join is not useful since it do not add the null rows.

Comment: "i want to join this two tables", what two tables, you only mention one...

Comment: the second table is obviously the second one i wrote.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious at all (until your edit). You described a table, then you mention possible values of `key` (who's to say `possible values` is an actual table), and finally you describe your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to this is two steps.  The first is to generate all the rows that you want in the output.  The second is to then assign the values.  The first uses `CROSS JOIN`.  The second `LEFT JOIN`.

If I assume you have a table of the ids, then:

```
select i.id, k.key, t.value
from ids i cross join
     keys k left join
     t
     on i.id = t.id and k.key = t.key;
```

If you don't have the ids in a separate table, you can do this with a subquery:

```
with ids as (
      select distinct id
      from t
     )
select i.id, k.key, t.value
from ids i cross join
     keys k left join
     t
     on i.id = t.id and k.key = t.key;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I want only to clarify that, in the first query, in my case both i and t are the same table, in my case the first one i wrote.